# Using wp_enqueue in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I turn to this awesome community , after days of trying to fix this bug, my problem is really simple, but it has got to me. I am trying to enqueue a Java script to my Theme my login Plugin while using the evolve theme.

here is the code snippet that does that, and i used the global function to check if the function is being loaded , and it is not being loaded. 'a' does not change to true.

For some reason it looks like 'wp_enqueue_scripts is not working. I have tried to also add wp_head() with no luck.

```html
  <?php
$GLOBALS['a'] = 'false';
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_location' );

function load_location() {
$GLOBALS['a'] = 'true';
 wp_register_script('load_location_test',get_template_directory_uri().'/load_location.js', array('jquery'),'1.1',true);
 wp_enqueue_script('load_location_test');
}

?>
<?php echo $GLOBALS['a'] ?>;
```

Thanks in advice

The link is http://www.meetntrain.com/register

Comment: Where did you add that code? it should be in your plugin or `functions.php`

Comment: This code is added to my Register form php form, does it have to go in the fuctions.php file ? I am using "theme my login" plugin, and editing the register form in my theme folder. Hope it is clear

Comment: Yes, it should be in your `functions.php`

Comment: Adding the Snippet to functions.php solved the issue, but the java script is now loaded on all the pages. I might have to add a condition on which page I want it to load. 

I thought I can use enqueuing on a specific page that I want the JS to be loaded on. thus adding it to my register form

Comment: You should be having a unique class for that page on your body. Wrap your JS in `if( $('body.thatClass').length ){ your code here }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for your enqueue to work, you need to add the code in your `functions.php` file or in your plugin.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_location' );

function load_location() {
    wp_register_script('load_location_test',get_template_directory_uri().'/load_location.js', array('jquery'),'1.1',true);
    wp_enqueue_script('load_location_test');
}
```

This will add the JS file to all your pages. If you want to target a specific page, you can either do it via JavaScript or directly in your PHP file.

If your theme uses [`body_class()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class), you can target that specific page by the class. You should then wrap your JS like:

```
if( $('body.classUsed').length ){
// Your JS code here
}
```

Note that the file will still be enqueued all the time. Alternately, if you want to add the JS file only to a specified page, you can wrap it in an [`is_page()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) condition:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_location' );

function load_location() {
    if( is_page('your-page') ){
       wp_register_script('load_location_test',get_template_directory_uri().'/load_location.js', array('jquery'),'1.1',true);
       wp_enqueue_script('load_location_test');
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the docs or at the files of other plugins, walkthroughs online, etc, to understand more. [wp_enqueue_scripts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) is a hook you're using to load your Javascript, and you have the basic right idea, but try something a little more like this inside your functions.php:

```
function my_custom_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'custom-js', 'js/custom.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-js', 'js/custom.js', false );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_scripts' );
```

Change out the "js/custom.js" for wherever your directory has your JS file.

Another option, if this is proving too tough, is to put a direct link to the JS file at the bottom of your footer.php. Like `<script src="/path/to/my/file.js"></script>`.

I do find the enqueuing scripts thing a little weird sometimes though, hope this helps you get it figured out.

Comment: Yeah , I had an idea about how hook works, but the function was not being called. Also the java script file was on the main directory (tried to put it there after being frustrated from hours of testing). Thanks for the alternative but I have might found the solution

Comment: Adding the Snippet to functions.php solved the issue, but the java script is now loaded on all the pages. I might have to add a condition on which page I want it to load. 

I thought I can use enqueuing on a specific page that I want the JS to be loaded on. thus adding it to my register form

Comment: Check this out for help on loading on specific pages. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-load-specific-java-script-on-specific-page?replies=9 (Davillan's answer)

You can do it a couple ways, again. Add a conditional tag and load a `<script></script>` or add a conditional inside the `my_custom_scripts` function to check for the page ID, url, whatever you want. PS: If the answer solved your issue as you said, please mark it as correct:)